# How to fix property of GADBannerView so a request can be loaded

Tags: swift, admob

I am getting this error:

```
2016-05-11 17:07:43.496 Inspire[2265:1045224] <Google> 
  You must set the        rootViewController property of 
  <GADBannerView: 0x136586cb0; frame = (47 0; 320 50); 
  clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = 
  <CALayer: 0x1365876b0>> before loading a request.
```

my `GADBannerView` does not appear at all.

How do I fix this problem to make it load?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, provide more information about the context of your issue !

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Put this

```
self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
```

In the code you have for your admob adbanner

```
 print("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: \(GADRequest.sdkVersion())")
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
    self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
    let request: GADRequest = GADRequest()
    self.bannerView.loadRequest(request)
```